# array.splice function in javascript

Tags: javascript, arrays, 2d-games

I am trying to make a stratego game and I am having trouble deleting enemy tokens from the board. Does array.splice(index,number) shorten the length of the array by number?

```
let map1 = [/* enemy pieces in a grid*/]       
let enemyPositions = [/* numeric positions of enemy pieces*/]          

// finds the value of piece\/
let attackVal = getTropperValue(pieceIndex);
let defenseVal = getTropperValue(pieceIndex+10);

// if the miner is attacking a bomb, the miner wins
if (attackVal===3 && defenseVal === 11 && facing === "down")
{
  setTimeout( () => removePiece(pieceIndex+10),1000);
  map1.splice(pieceIndex+10,1,"");
  enemyPositions.splice(pieceIndex+10,1);
}
```

Comment: "*Does array.splice(index,number) shorten the length of the array by number?*" the answer is yes. But I'm not sure how that answer helps you. You better describe the problem you have.

Comment: _"shorten the length of the array by number"_ - kinda? `a = [0,1,2,3,4]; a.splice(2);` will result in `a` being `[0,1]`

Comment: I outputed the array to the console, but in the space that I deleted it says <9 empty items>

Comment: @bebro22 please make sure the example in the question is a [mcve]? We can't debug what we can't see.

Comment: sorry, I'm new to this

Comment: _“Does array.splice(index,number) do X?”_ — Read the [documentation](//developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/splice).

Answer (score 1):

The splice method works as following:
The first parameter specifies the index of the first item you want to remove.
The second parameter specifies how many items you want to remove.
It returns a new array containing the items removed

Take a look at the example

```js
const arr = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9];
const arr2 = arr.splice(4, 2);
```

At the end we have

```
arr  [ 1, 2, 3, 4, 7, 8, 9 ]
arr2 [ 5, 6 ]
```

So for example, if you want to remove only the n'th item, you should use...

```js
arr.splice(n - 1, 1);
```

Comment: so splice doesn't actually change the array it's invoked on?

Comment: It does. Read again the state of ``arr``, it's missing 5 and 6, those numbers are in ``arr2``